# PhpStorm wrap traits

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

In PhpStorm, how would I make traits wrap? Under `Editor | Code Style | PHP -> Wrapping and Braces` there is no option to wrap traits.

I want to wrap my traits like so:

```
class Foo {

    use Concerns\SomeTrait,
        Concerns\AnotherTrait;

}
```

But PhpStorm automatically turns them into a oneliner:

```
class Foo {

    use Concerns\SomeTrait, Concerns\AnotherTrait;

}
```

Does any one know where this can be changed?

Comment: So far I have found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21697 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11827

Comment: @LazyOne Great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `settings`/`Editor`/`Code Style`/`PHP` and check the option to keep line breaks when formatting:

[image]

Comment: Perfect thanks ;) Id rather have them create a separate option for wrapping traits though, as I could think of situations in which you dont want to keep line breaks when reformating